# Concatenate a String to all elements of a Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code that parses a `Spliterator<Map.Entry>` to a `Map`:

```
Spliterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> spliterator = ///;

Map<String, String> myMap = (StreamSupport
  .stream(spliterator, false)
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

I want to change the code such as in my `myMap`, every key is concatenated with a constant String. Something like that :

```
Spliterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> spliterator = ///;
String myString = "hello";
String separator = "_";

Map<String, String> myMap = (StreamSupport
  .stream(spliterator, false)
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(myString+separator+Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

I understand why this is not working but I don't find the good way to do that (without iterating over `myMap` after the stream). I am not familiar with Streams in Java so I probably missed something obvious.

Comment: Must you use a spliterator? Do you really just want a new Map with all keys modified by adding a string? How about `Map<String, String> myMap = map.entrySet().stream().collect(toMap(e -> myString + separator + e.getKey(), Map.Entry::getValue));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `myString+separator+Map.Entry::getKey` because `Map.Entry::getKey` is not a string but a method reference. You should instead use a lambda:

```
entry -> myString + separator + entry.getKey()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an explicit lambda function instead of a method reference:

```
.collect(toMap(
    e -> myString + separator + e.getKey(),
    Map.Entry::getValue
))
```